# mysql Creating a Generated Column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a new column in an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`.`data` 
ADD COLUMN `IndSale` DECIMAL(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (sum(TotalSale / 
Quantity)) VIRTUAL AFTER `InvoiceComment`;
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1111: Invalid use of group function
```

I don't understand what function is considered "group function"?

Comment: OK after playing around some more, I realize that I should not have put "sum" in the statement.  After taking it out, I am no longer getting an error, but the column rows are just displaying "0.00"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM` is a group/aggregate function; it is used in queries such as:

`SELECT id, SUM(values) FROM aTable GROUP BY id;`

Edit: After Barmar's info below, it dawned on me where to check in the docs...

Without knowing the details of your table, I am guessing something like this would be what you intented:

```
IndSale` DECIMAL(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS TotalSale/Quantity
```

Comment: Generated columns were added in 5.7.

Comment: This did work, the columns that I was using to generate this column did not have any data, hence the reason I was getting 0.00.